# Divide an array into k segments to maximize the bitwise and

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming, partitioning, bitwise-and

We have a divide a array of size n(1<=n<=50) into k segments(1<=k<=n) such that the bitwise and of the resultant value of the segments is maximum possible. the value of a segment is denoted by the sum of elements present in it. I feel the question might be answered using dynamic programming but somehow cant identify the states needed. The crucial thing is the value of n is very small. Can we use it to our advantage somehow? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621259/partition-of-array-into-k-contiguous-subarrays-such-that-bitwise-and-of-sum-of-e

Comment: Possible duplicate of [partition of array into k contiguous subarrays such that bitwise AND of sum of each subarray is maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621259/partition-of-array-into-k-contiguous-subarrays-such-that-bitwise-and-of-sum-of-e)

Comment: @SeanVanGorder from what I've seen, for a question to be considered a duplicate on SO, the referenced question ought to have an _accepted_ answer.