# partition of array into k contiguous subarrays such that bitwise AND of sum of each subarray is maximum

Tags: java, algorithm

An array of size `n` (n<=50) containing positive integers is given.
You have to divide the array into `k` contiguous subarrays in such a way that the bitwise `AND` of all subarray sums is maximized.

For example with `array=[30,15,26,16,21]` and `k=3`, consider all partitions:

- (30) & (15) & (26+16+21) = 14
- (30) & (15+26) & (16+21) = 0
- (30) & (15+26+16) & (21) = 16
- (30+15) & (26+16) & (21) = 0
- (30+15) & (26) & (16+21) = 0
- (30+15+26) & (16) & (21) = 0

Maximum of all is 16, so the answer for this array is 16.

I am not getting any idea other than brute force. Please help.

```
static void findMaxAND(int[] arr,int k){
        if (k>arr.length){
            System.out.println(0);
            return;
        }
        int n=arr.length;
        int[] parSum=new int[n];
        parSum[0]=arr[0];
        for (int i=1;i<n;i++){
            parSum[i]+=parSum[i-1]+arr[i];
        }

        int upperSum=parSum[n-1]/k;
        int upperBit=(int)Math.floor((Math.log10(upperSum)/Math.log10(2)));

        partitions=new ArrayList<>();
        while (true){
            int min=(int)Math.pow(2,upperBit);

            check(arr,min,-1,new ArrayList<>(),1,k);
            if (!partitions.isEmpty()){
                int maxAND=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                for (List<Integer> partiton:partitions){
                    partiton.add(n-1);
                    int innerAND=parSum[partiton.get(0)];
                    for (int i=1;i<partiton.size();i++){
                        innerAND&=(parSum[partiton.get(i)]-parSum[partiton.get(i-1)]);
                    }

                    maxAND=Math.max(maxAND,innerAND);
                }
                System.out.println(maxAND);
                break;
            }

            upperBit--;
        }
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> partitions;

    static void check(int[] arr,int min,int lastIdx,List<Integer> idxs,int currPar,int k){
        int sum=0;
        if (currPar==k){
            if (lastIdx>=arr.length-1){
                return;
            }
            int i=lastIdx+1;
            while (i<arr.length){
                sum+=arr[i];
                i++;
            }
            if ((sum&min)!=0){
                partitions.add(new ArrayList<>(idxs));
            }
        }
        if (currPar>k||lastIdx>=(arr.length-1)){
            return;
        }

        sum=0;
        for (int i=lastIdx+1;i<arr.length;i++){
            sum+=arr[i];
            if ((sum&min)!=0){
                idxs.add(i);
                check(arr,min,i,idxs,currPar+1,k);
                idxs.remove(idxs.size()-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

It is working but time complexity is too bad.

Comment: I would concentrate on one bit at a time. The array total is 108. So given k=3, the maximum possible answer is 36. So start with bit value 32, and see if you can partition the array into sums that all have bit 32 set. If that's not possible, try to partition into sums that all have bit 16 set. And so on.

Comment: i think this will work. can you give further explanation.thanks

Comment: It would help if you posted the code that generates the partitions for your brute force solution. My suggestion is just an optimization on that. Note that I assume that you **aren't** using a library call that generates all the partitions for you.

Comment: @user3386109 i have added the code

Comment: In the `check` method, a subarray is valid when `((sum & min) != 0)`.

Comment: yes.But it does not affect the complexity.

Comment: If you have `k` levels of recursion, and three choices at each level, the complexity is 3^k. If you can eliminate one of the choices at each level, the complexity is reduced to 2^k. In the example, the first partition is (30), (30+15), or (30+15+26). Only one of those has bit 32 set. Only one has bit 16. So you actually eliminate two of the choices at the top level of recursion. OTOH, if you compare `sum > min`, then two choices are greater than 32, and all three choices are greater than 16.

Comment: @user3386109 How do i change this to dynamic programming.

Comment: To apply dynamic programming, you must identify subproblems that will appear multiple times as the algorithm progresses. In this case, a subproblem could be defined as the AND of the sums so far, the number of items still unused, and the number of partitions remaining. So for example, if you start with `(30) & (15+26)`, the subproblem is {8,2,1} since `(30) & (15+26) = 8` and there are 2 items in the array that haven't been used, and there's 1 partition left to make. If you start with `(30+15) & (26)`, the subproblem is also {8,2,1}. So there is some hope that dynamic programming will work.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a non-recursive dynamic-programming solution (in JavaScript, though it should be very straightforward to port it to Java). It works in a similar way to what user3386109's comment and גלעד ברקן's answer suggest, though I'm not sure if it's exactly the same. (It performed much better than גלעד ברקן's answer when I tested it, but that might be due to minor implementation differences rather than meaningful conceptual differences.)

Its overall complexity is worst-case *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>*kb*) time and *O*(*nk*) extra space, where *b* is the number of bits to try — I just hardcoded it to 31 below, which performed just fine in practice, though you can optimize it if desired by ruling out larger numbers. (N.B. I'm assuming here that additions and bitwise-ANDs are *O*(1). If we have to support *really* large numbers, then the actual worst-case time complexity will be *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>*kb*<sup>2</sup>).)

See code comments for details.

```js
function f(array, numSegments) {
  const n = array.length;
  const maxBit = (1 << 30); // note: can improve if desired

  if (numSegments > n) {
    throw 'Too many segments.';
  }

  /* prefixSums[i] will be the sum of array[0..(i-1)], so that
   * the sum of array[i..j] will be prefixSums[j+1]-prefixSums[i].
   * This is a small optimization and code simplification, but the
   * same asymptotic complexity is possible without it.
   */
  const prefixSums = [];
  prefixSums[0] = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    prefixSums.push(prefixSums[i-1] + array[i-1]);
  }

  /* bestKnownBitmask will be the result -- the best bitmask that we
   * could achieve. It will grow by one bit at a time; for example,
   * if the correct answer is binary 1011, then bestKnownBitmask will
   * start out as 0000, then later become 1000, then later 1010, and
   * finally 1011.
   */
  let bestKnownBitmask = 0;

  /* startIndices[seg] will be a list of start-indices where
   * it's possible to divide the range from such a start-index to
   * the end of the array into 'seg' segments whose sums all satisfy
   * a given bitmask condition.
   *
   * In particular, startIndices[0] will always be [n], because the
   * only way to get zero segments is to have zero elements left; and
   * startIndices[numSegments][0] will always be 0, because we only
   * keep a bitmask condition if we successfully found a way to
   * partition the entire array (0..(n-1)) into 'numSegments' segments
   * whose sums all satisfied it.
   */
  let startIndices = [];
  startIndices.push([n]);
  for (let seg = 1; seg <= numSegments; ++seg) {
    startIndices.push([]);
    for (let i = numSegments - seg; i <= n - seg; ++i) {
      startIndices[seg].push(i);
    }
  }

  for (let currBit = maxBit; currBit > 0; currBit >>= 1) {
    const bitmaskToTry = (bestKnownBitmask | currBit);

    const tmpStartIndices = startIndices.map(row => []); // empty copy
    tmpStartIndices[0].push(n);

    for (let seg = 1; seg <= numSegments; ++seg) {
      for (const startIndex of startIndices[seg]) {
        for (const nextIndex of tmpStartIndices[seg-1]) {
          if (nextIndex <= startIndex) {
            continue;
          }
          const segmentSum = prefixSums[nextIndex] - prefixSums[startIndex];
          if ((segmentSum & bitmaskToTry) === bitmaskToTry) {
            tmpStartIndices[seg].push(startIndex);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (tmpStartIndices[numSegments].length > 0
        && tmpStartIndices[numSegments][0] === 0) {
      // success!
      bestKnownBitmask = bitmaskToTry;
      startIndices = tmpStartIndices;
    }
  }

  return bestKnownBitmask;
}

function runFunctionAndLogResult(array, numSegments) {
  let startTime = performance.now();
  let result = f(array, numSegments);
  let endTime = performance.now();
  console.log(
    'array = [' + array.join(', ') + ']\n' +
    'k = ' + numSegments + '\n' +
    'result = ' + result + '\n' +
    'time = ' + (endTime - startTime) + ' ms'
  );
}

runFunctionAndLogResult(
  [ 25, 40, 45, 69, 26, 13, 49, 49, 84, 67, 30, 22, 43, 82, 2, 95, 96, 63, 78, 26, 95, 57, 80, 8, 85, 23, 64, 85, 12, 66, 74, 69, 9, 35, 69, 89, 34, 2, 60, 91, 79, 99, 64, 57, 52, 56, 89, 20, 8, 85 ],
  12
);
```

Comment: (+1) I've added the example you provided in a comment under my answer to the list of examples that are run in my snippet. It seems to work instantly. To illustrate your code performing "much better," please provide some kind of repeatable reference.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: I've never tried this "code snippet" feature before, but OK, I've just given it a whirl. Is this what you had in mind? (Interestingly, it runs *much* slower than the way I was running it before. I'm not sure if that's the overhead of the "code snippet" feature, or what.)

Comment: That's cool. I get about 12-16ms on yours and upwards of 50-60ms for mine with the snippets. So yeah, significant difference but still a few orders of magnitude from the real brute force.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea with a reference to user3386109's suggestion in the comments, although instead of having the possible `AND` of a subarray as a parameter, we have the current highest set bit.

Given a prefix with highest set bit `b`, we'd like to return all `AND` combinations with suffixes that have `b` set. If there are none, we can't use this bit so try a lower one. Note that the values generated from all possible partitions that have the highest fixed bit set will necessarily include the best overall answer among them.

The recursion below has `left_index, right_index, current_k, bth_bit_set` as parameters (and search space) and a list of possible values as a result. We apply memoization both to a single call and to the aggregation of calls for a range of calls with a fixed left and varying right index (seems like brute force, no?).

JavaScript code follows (not sure if this consistently works :) Unless I made some mistake, or it's really hard to get degenerate data, it seems like fixing the high bit, as user3386109 suggested, prunes the search space substantially.

```js
function f(arr, K){
  let str = `Array:\n${ arr.join('\n') }` + 
            `\n\nK: ${ K }\n\n`

  let hash = {
    f: {},
    f_range: {}
  }

  function g(l, r, k, b, A, K){
    // Out of bounds
    if (r > A.length - 1 || k > K || b < 0)
      return []

    if (hash.f.hasOwnProperty([l, r, k, b]))
      return hash.f[[l, r, k, b]]
      
    let s = pfxs[r] - pfxs[l-1]
    
    // This sum does not have
    // the bth bit set
    if (!(s & (1 << b)))
      return hash.f[[l, r, k, b]] = []
      
    if (r == A.length - 1){
      if (k < K)
        return hash.f[[l, r, k, b]] = []
      else
        return hash.f[[l, r, k, b]] = [s]
    }
    
    if (k == K){
      if (r == A.length - 1)
        return hash.f[[l, r, k, b]] = s & (1 << b) ? [s] : []
      else
        return hash.f[[l, r, k, b]] = g(l, r + 1, k, b, A, K)
    }
    
    // Possible suffixes
    let sfxs = []
    // Number of parts outstanding
    let ks = K - k
    // Upper bound for next part
    let ub = A.length - ks + 1
    
    if (hash.f_range.hasOwnProperty([r + 1, ub, k + 1, b])){
      sfxs = hash.f_range[[r + 1, ub, k + 1, b]]

    } else {
      for (let rr=r+1; rr<ub; rr++)
        sfxs = sfxs.concat(
          g(r + 1, rr, k + 1, b, A, K)
        )
      hash.f_range[[r + 1, ub, k + 1, b]] = sfxs
    }
        
    // We have a possible solution
    if (sfxs.length){
      result = []
      
      for (let sfx of sfxs)
        result.push(s & sfx)
      
      return hash.f[[l, r, k, b]] = result
    
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }

  // Array's prefix sums
  let pfxs = [arr[0]]
  for (let i=1; i<arr.length; i++)
    pfxs[i] = arr[i] + pfxs[i - 1]
  pfxs[-1] = 0

  let highBit = -1

  let maxNum = arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)
  while (maxNum){
    highBit++
    maxNum >>= 1
  }

  str += `\nhigh bit: ${ highBit }`

  let best = 0

  for (let b=highBit; b>=0; b--){
    for (let r=0; r<arr.length-K+1; r++){
      let result = g(0, r, 1, b, arr, K)
      //str += `\n${ JSON.stringify(result) }`
      if (result.length)
        best = Math.max(best, Math.max.apply(null, result))
    }
    if (best)
      break
  }
  console.log(str + '\n')
  return best
}

let arr = [30, 15, 26, 16, 21]
let K = 3
console.log(`result: ${ f(arr, K) }\n\n`)

let rand_arr = []
let rand_len = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 49)
for (let i=0; i<rand_len; i++){
  let rand_exp = ~~(Math.random() * 30)
  rand_arr[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (1 << rand_exp))
}
let rand_k = Math.ceil(Math.random() * rand_len)

console.log(`result: ${ f(rand_arr, rand_k) }\n\n`)

const ex = [ 25, 40, 45, 69, 26, 13, 49, 49, 84, 67, 30, 22, 43, 82, 2, 95, 96, 63, 78, 26, 95, 57, 80, 8, 85, 23, 64, 85, 12, 66, 74, 69, 9, 35, 69, 89, 34, 2, 60, 91, 79, 99, 64, 57, 52, 56, 89, 20, 8, 85 ]

console.log(`result: ${ f(ex, 12) }`)
```

Sample output

```
Array:
9598
15283236
121703215
80
25601067
761
7071
428732360
238244
2
176
116076
4
3517
491766404
5619908
39459923
330411
8
38

K: 5


high bit: 30

result: 4259840
```

More sample output:

```
Array:
3853
7668
77853
1
3
6652
166
2
5
15323609
17252
3422
1
122913
8
17
89263
21934
332522269
44900
1014
2503905
449429594
4190
3
166469508
1
898071

K: 3


high bit: 29
result: 12713984
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191822/discussion-on-answer-by---partition-of-array-into-k-contiguous-subarrays).